# Codeception: Force PhpBrowser to use custom environment

Tags: codeception

I have a page with a text field and button. After I fill out text field and press a button my controller is connecting to an API and getting some data based on the text.

I prepared a `FAKE_API` for testing. Both `REAL_API` and `FAKE_API` are in the service container. The `FAKE_API` is being prioritized when the environment is set to `test` (`.env.test` file). The controller gets the API object via dependency injection (constructor argument).

When I am  testing using `PhpBrowser` from `Codeception`, the environment **of the test itself** is set to `test` - this can be checked by `var_dump($_ENV['APP_ENV'])` from the test.

However, (and this is the issue), if I add `var_dump($_ENV['APP_ENV'])` to the controller code and run the same test, I can see that the controller actually uses the regular 'dev' environment (set in `.env` file). This means that the `REAL API` is being used instead of my `FAKE_API`.

How can I force PhpBrowser tests to use my `.env.test`? Is it even possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/5411 help?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

PhpBrowser communicates to system under test via HTTP, so it can't set environment variables of the system.

Your options are:

- Deploy API in test configuration
- Pass environment using GET or POST parameters or headers and make your app code accept it. (this is a bad idea)